# ng-if expression evaluating incorrectly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've just across a weird 'quirk', and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Here's the code, with a Plunkr link below:

**HTML**

```
<!-- Shows nothing if bar === 'N', BUT shows any other letter. -->
<div ng-if="foo.bar">ng-if: {{ foo.bar }}</div>

<!-- Shows nothing is bar === 'N', BUT shows any other letter. -->
<div ng-show="foo.bar">ng-show: {{ foo.bar }}</div>

<!-- Works in all cases -->
<div ng-hide="!foo.bar">ng-hide: {{ foo.bar }}</div>

<button ng-click="foo.select('B')">Select 'B'</button>
<button ng-click="foo.select('N')">Select 'N'</button>
<button ng-click="foo.reset()">Reset</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MainController', function($scope) {

  $scope.foo = {
    baz: 'foo'
  };

  $scope.foo.select = function(item) {
    $scope.foo.bar = item;
  }

  $scope.foo.reset = function() {
    $scope.foo.bar = '';
  }
});
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/H3Ghk1dCQqQ5PVd30Pdp?p=preview

In the example, why when you select 'N' is it not shown? In my actual app, the whole alphabet it used, and only the letter 'N' doesn't work. This doesn't make any sense to me, in plain JavaScript, the following apply:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = {};
obj.foo.bar = 'N';

!!obj.foo.bar
// => true
```

And I assumed `ng-if / ng-show` displayed content based on the expression being 'truthy'?

Any help would be amazing, I'm hoping it's just a misunderstanding that I've made!

Comment: Quick fix is to use `!!foo.bar`. http://plnkr.co/edit/Nm31s7pBLDyzFZrhMyHF?p=preview

Comment: If you can read German look at this post: http://angularjs.de/blog/ng-show-verhalten

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Believe it or not this is actually a feature. More accurately, it was a feature because it's been removed from the 1.3.0 beta.

Here is the [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/bdfc9c02d021e08babfbc966a007c71b4946d69d) which removed it. The commit message states:

> values `'f'`, `'0'`, `'false'`, `'no'`, `'n'`, `'[]'` are no longer
>   treated as falsy. Only JavaScript falsy values are now treated as falsy by the
>   expression parser; there are six of them: `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `0` and `""`.

Comment: Amazing! Funnily enough I just noticed it happened on the letter 'F' too and thought it would be something like that! Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. I had no idea this was a feature until I read your question. I'm glad it's been removed.